# Pipeline software or frameworks for moving data from logstash to Redshift?

Tags: gratis, open-source, redshift

Looking for some existing pipelining software/methods for moving the data from Logstash(using an ELK stack) to AWS Redshift.

ELK: Elasticsearch-Logstash-Kibana

I have already worked with [Luigi](http://luigi.readthedocs.org/en/stable/), but I am looking for methods/software which are industry tested and widely used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have been dabbling with this problem, and finally architected a solution to the problem, and here is how you do it.

ElasticSearch has an [output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-s3.html) which writes the log files to S3 in batches.

So, as soon as the file_size is filled, the file is pushed into a pre-specified S3 bucket and the next file is taken for writing.

And the S3 data can be written to Redshift, either through the [COPY command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-copydata-redshift.html), or write advanced cron jobs through a Luigi scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You could write directly from logstash to S3 using [S3 output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-s3.html) and then use [AWS lambda loader](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-redshift-loader) to load the data into Redshift.